# Problem knitting LaTex maths expression as Beamer Presentation

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown, beamer

I want to knit some maths expressions and also some Greek letters (in maths) as a Beamer Presentation in R. While the maths formulas were knitted successfully, I don't know why R was failed to knit all the Greek letters.
You can reproduce the result using this:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "John Doe"
date: "11/1/2021"
output: beamer_presentation
---

## THIS WORKS

- Standalone equation.
\[
\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
\]

- In an aligned environment.
$$
\begin{aligned}
e^{i\pi} + 1 &= 0 \\
\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}
e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(x-\mu\right)^2/\sigma^2}\,\mathrm{d}x &= 1\\
\int^{\sqrt[3]{3}}_1 z^2 \, \mathrm{d}z \times \cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{9}\right) &= \log\left(\sqrt[3]{e}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

## THIS DOESN'T WORK

\[H_o: \mu_1 = \mu_2 \]
\[H_1: \mu_1 \gt \mu_2 \]
```

Can someone suggest how I can solve this? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to do with greek letters, the `\gt` is the problem. Use `>` :

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "John Doe"
date: "11/1/2021"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    keep_tex: true
---

## THIS WORKS

- Standalone equation.
\[
\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
\]

- In an aligned environment.
$$
\begin{aligned}
e^{i\pi} + 1 &= 0 \\
\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}
e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(x-\mu\right)^2/\sigma^2}\,\mathrm{d}x &= 1\\
\int^{\sqrt[3]{3}}_1 z^2 \, \mathrm{d}z \times \cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{9}\right) &= \log\left(\sqrt[3]{e}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

## THIS DOESN'T WORK

\[H_o: \mu_1 = \mu_2 \]
\[H_1: \mu_1 > \mu_2 \]
```

[image]

Comment: This is odd. `\gt` is perfectly fine & [acceptable in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). The culprit seems to be `beamer_presentation`. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Mathjax does not use latex at all - it just emulates parts of the syntax. This has nothing to do with beamer, you would get the same error in every other latex class as well.

Comment: I was hoping that `pandoc` would take care of different output flavours. For example, if you change the output to `html_document` there is no error. In that case, all LaTeX-type expressions are rendered using MathJax. The problem is that `\gt` seems to break being able to switch to different outputs without having to change the main text body. I wonder if this is a bug?

Comment: @MauritsEvers If I change the output to `html_document`,  `>` still seems to work fine - why don't you want to use it?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Perfect! I've fixed it and it works like charm. Thank you! Is there any cheatsheet for the Beamer in R markdown that I could look at? It's just annoying when they just use different LaTex codes when knitting in R ughh.

Comment: @NganKD I'm not aware of anything specific to beamer in rmarkdown, but here is a good cheatsheet for real beamer: http://science.thilucmic.fr/index.php?c=la&p=beamersheet